# nginx reverse proxy from rails to wordpress

Tags: ruby-on-rails, wordpress, url, nginx, reverse-proxy

I have a Ruby on Rails application and a Wordpress blog hosted on separate EC2 instances.

**I'm trying to make the Wordpress blog to act like a subfolder of the Rails application (example.com/blog instead of blog.example.com) for better SEO**

- The Rails application can be accessed through http and https (http is redirecting to https)

https://www.nginx.com/resources/admin-guide/reverse-proxy/

I tried using nginx reverse proxy function and I think it's my best option right now but my attempt was unsuccessful.

1. The main page of the blog opens as expected (example.com/blog) but
   without css.
2. A URL with arguements (example.com/blog/args) redirects me back to
   the Rails application (example.com/args)

I set the desired blog url in wp-config.php as the following:

```
define('WP_SITEURL', 'https://www.example.com/blog');
define('WP_HOME', 'https://www.example.com/blog');
```

**This is the nginx configuration I use:**

```
  location ^~ /blog {
   proxy_pass http://<<BLOGIP>>/blog;
   proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
   proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
  }
```

- https://github.com/waterlink/rack-reverse-proxy
  I also tried the
  rack-reverse-proxy gem but got the same result

It's really important for the Rails application and the Wordpress blog to stay separated for auto-scaling, redundancy and deployment purposes.

If there's another way achieving this, I'm open to suggestions.

Comment: Can you first get your blog working directly using `https://www.example.com/blog` then it would be easier to proxy_pass

Comment: @TarunLalwani No man, I installed it using a pre-built image on Amazon

Comment: @TarunLalwani I've managed to route /blog to Wordpress on it's server. You're saying that now the nginx config should work properly?

Comment: Yes if it works there now nginx reverse proxy also should work

Comment: @TarunLalwani it's working but doesn't load css and js because chrome says it's unsafe. My Rails application is using SSL and the Wordpress is not. Do you know how can I fix this?

Comment: The question has your final config?

Comment: @TarunLalwani 
I edited the question, now it has the final config

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153852/discussion-between-tarun-lalwani-and-maxdbn).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now that you have your blog working at `http://<blogip>/blog` you need fix few more things

```
location ^~ /blog { 
   proxy_pass http://<<BLOG_IP>>/blog; 
   proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr; 
   proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for; 

   proxy_redirect http://<ip>/ https://$host/;
   proxy_cookie_domain <ip> $host;
   proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

}
```

Also add below to your `wp-config.php`

```
define('FORCE_SSL_ADMIN', true); 

if ( isset( $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO'] ) && $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO'] == 'https') 
$_SERVER['HTTPS']='on';
```

Comment: Just to make sure, <ip> is the same should be the BLOG ip, right? I did that but the assets are still picked up from http://

Answer (score 2):

Solved with Tarun Lalwani's help

1. Wordpress should be accessable from

   > blog-ip/blog
2. nginx config on example.com

   ```
     location ^~ /blog {
       proxy_pass http://<<blog-ip>>/blog;
       proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
       proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
       proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

       proxy_redirect http://<<blog-ip>>/ https://$host/;
       proxy_cookie_domain <<blog-ip>> $host;
     }
   ```
3. added this to wp-config.php

   ```
   define('FORCE_SSL_ADMIN', true);

   if ( isset( $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO'] ) && $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO'] == 'https')
       $_SERVER['HTTPS']='on';
   ```
4. changed the url

   ```
   define('WP_SITEURL', 'https://www.example.com/blog');
   define('WP_HOME', 'https://www.example.com/blog');
   ```

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative solution, you could use [AWS CDN CloudFront](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/Introduction.html) and have multiple origins. One origin for your site and other for the blog. (separated so you can scale them apart)

For setting up WordPress you could follow this post: http://www.danneh.org/2015/04/setting-wordpress-amazon-cloudfront/

Within your CloudFront Distribution the Behaviors, the `Path Pattern` may look like this:

[image: cloudfront path pattern]

Within the CDN you could do the "http to https" besides also only [allowing traffic](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/how-to-automatically-update-your-security-groups-for-amazon-cloudfront-and-aws-waf-by-using-aws-lambda/) from CloudFront if required.

Your Nginx conf regarding the `location` may look like this:

```
location /blog {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /blog/index.php;
}
```

The `/blog` is because CloudFront won't remove the `Path Patterns` so all request to your origins will be prefixed with `/blog`

Comment: Will this work if the blog is under root path on it's server and not /blog?
https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/98520/wordpress-reverse-proxy-with-cloudfront-and-s3

I'm really confused on how to make this work. Can you please elaborate on how to make a reverse proxy from example.com/blog to blog.example.com and example.com as the main server?

Comment: The tricky part is moving WordPress to be served from the  `/blog` directory mainly because CloudFront won't remove the `/blog` in the request, probably with some Nginx rewrite conditions could be solved.

Comment: I've managed to move the blog to /blog on it's server. 
Please tell me if I understand this right, I should create an origin with the domain blog.example.com with /blog* path and make example.com as an alternate domain?

Comment: your first origin will be something like `mainsite.example.com` Default(*), your second origin will be `blog.example.com` and there in the Behaviors you will create a `Path Pattern` "/blog*"

Comment: I did what you said, made a distribution with the origin example.com with the default settings, then added another origin blog.example.com and finally a behavior for /blog* path for the blog origin, but example.com/blog redirects me to the main page of my Rails application (there I have a rule that any unset route will redirect to the main page) 
I don't understand how this thing works

Comment: check this http://robido.com/nginx/nginx-wordpress-subdirectory-configuration-example/